# When i try to get task via Get-scheduleTask show error

Tags: powershell

When i try to get schedule task in windows 10 1903 via powershell with get-scheduledtask show follwing error

```
Get-ScheduledTask : Invalid namespace
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ScheduledTask
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (MSFT_ScheduledTask:Root/Microsoft/...T_ScheduledTask) [Get-ScheduledTask
   ], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x8004100e,Get-ScheduledTask`
```

I check ps version :

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $PSVersionTable
```

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.18362.752
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.18362.752
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

What should i do ?

Comment: Try repairing or reinstalling the .NET framework.

Comment: See `Get-Module ScheduledTasks` if nothing shows up then check the filepath `C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules` for the folder `ScheduledTasks` and if it is not there try copying the files from http://103.214.144.26/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/Modules/ScheduledTasks/ into a `ScheduledTasks` folder